# Visual Code: "requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs."

Tags: android, flutter

```
   1.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-33.

       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 7.3.0 is 33.

       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
       compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).
```

2. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   ```
   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.3.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
   ```

I tried to change the version of the SDK but it keeps returning the same error